# ArcGIS Server 10.1 - Cached tiles cut off features

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1, features, extents

I have a, ArcGIS MapServer with cached tiles. The problem I ran into is, that the features which are next to the MapServers extent are cut off. 
The image below should explain the issue.
The blue line displays the x-min value of the extent. As you can see, only the half of the feature-icon is visible.
How can I tell my MapServer to cache the tiles with all features visible. Is there any way to specify some kind of padding to the extent?

[image]

Comment: What is  "ArcGIS Mapserver" ?? . I am confuse (Is it ArcGIS Desktop and UMN Map-server ?)

Comment: I use a ArcGIS Server 10.1 and published my Map as a service. Then I request it's data via the REST endpoint e.g. http://sandbox/arcgis/rest/services/test/MapServer/export. Sorry for not pointing this out

Answer (score 3):

Ok I solved this. I had to specify a bigger extent on the DataFrame in ArcMap before I published the service. Before the extent was set just to the extent of the featuerlayer in the DataFrame.